# What’s the name of this figure of speech?

Tags: english, terminology, semantics, figure-of-speech

Saying “The not tall boy” instead of “The short boy” does it have a name?

Comment: A little unusual syntax, but that could be litotes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_rhetorical_terms

Comment: @JeremyNeedle, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JeremyNeedle please turn your comment into a full-featured answer so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using what I understand to be the ‘classic’ rhetorical terms, I think this is *litotes*: using a negative statement (‘not tall’) to convey an understated positive one (‘short’). This term is included on this Wikipedia page with many others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_rhetorical_terms

(As an aside, I want to note the structure of your example is a little unusual to me. I think I am more used to seeing something like, “Is he short? Well, the boy is not tall.”, as opposed to “Where is the not tall boy?” )